# ITextSharp - fit PdfPCell width to text phrase

Tags: width, itext, cell

I'm trying to find out how to fit every width of PdfPCell to the text width. I don;t have a fixed amount of cells so every time this number is different and I want all the cells to have only a width of text, and not the same for every cell in table.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: As you've discovered, `PdfPTable` requires you to provide the column widths in advance. The content of the cells adapts to the width of the columns, not the other way around. That is a design choice. If you want the column widths to adapt to the content of the cells, you'll have to calculate the widths of the content first (the `Chunk` objects). You'll have to make several design decisions: what if a `Phrase` needs to be distributed over two lines? what if the content doesn't fit a row? And so on.

Comment: Thanks. I've calculated cell content width by Chunk and that helped.